# How to load and save StringGrid content?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-2010, delphi-xe

First part of the code works OK while the second (commented) does not.
It overwrites my A1 file although it should write to A2.

```
procedure TForm1.AdvGlowButton12Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i,j: Integer;
  Seznam: TStrings;
  ApplicationPath: string;
begin
  if (cxRadiogroup3.ItemIndex and cxRadiogroup2.ItemIndex) = 0 then begin
    ApplicationPath:= ExtractFileDir(Application.ExeName);
    Seznam:= TStringList.Create;
    try
      for i:=0 to advStringGrid2.ColCount-1 do
        Seznam.AddStrings(advStringGrid2.Cols [i]);
      for i:=0 to advStringGrid2.rowCount-1 do
        Seznam.AddStrings(advStringGrid2.rows [j]);
      Seznam.SaveToFile(ApplicationPath+'\A1.txt');
    finally
      seznam.free;
    end;
  end ;
  //if cxRadiogroup3.ItemIndex = 1 and cxRadiogroup2.ItemIndex = 0 then begin
  //  ApplicationPath:= ExtractFileDir(Application.ExeName);
  //  Seznam:= TStringList.Create;
  //  try
  //    for i:=0 to advStringGrid2.ColCount-1 do
  //      Seznam.AddStrings(advStringGrid2.Cols [i]);
  //    for i:=0 to advStringGrid2.rowCount-1 do
  //      Seznam.AddStrings(advStringGrid2.rows [j]);
  //    Seznam.SaveToFile(ApplicationPath+'\A2.txt');
  //  finally
  //    seznam.free;
  //  end ;
  //end
end;
```

What am I doing wrong ?
Also why is the stringgrid giving listindex out of bounds when I try to load into it contents from an empty text file? If I save empty stringgrid to that file,later ,though it has nothing in the file,it does not complain? Strange...

This is how I load A1 and A2 into the stringgrid.

```
procedure TForm1.cxRadioGroup2Click(Sender: TObject);
Var
  I,j,k: Integer;
  Seznam: TStrings;
  ApplicationPath: string;
begin
  case cxradioGroup2.ItemIndex of
    0: begin
         if cxradioGroup3.ItemIndex = 0 then begin
           Seznam:= TStringList.Create;
           AdvStringgrid2.ClearAll;
           try
             Seznam.LoadFromFile('A1.txt');
             k:= 0;
             for i:=0 to advStringGrid2.ColCount-1 do
               for j:=0 to advStringGrid2.RowCount-1 do begin
                 advstringGrid2.Cells [i,j]:= Seznam.Strings [k];
                 Inc(k);
               end;
           finally
             seznam.free;
           end;
         end;
         if cxradioGroup3.ItemIndex = 1 then begin
           Seznam:= TStringList.Create;
           AdvStringgrid2.ClearAll;
           try
             Seznam.LoadFromFile('A2.txt');
             k:=0;
             for i:=0 to advStringGrid2.ColCount-1 do
               for j:=0 to advStringGrid2.RowCount-1 do begin
                 advstringGrid2.Cells [i,j]:= Seznam.Strings [k];
                 Inc(k);
               end;
           finally
             seznam.free;
           end;
         end;
       end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: You need to show your loading code before someone can tell you why it reports index errors.

Comment: Code has been updated above ...

Comment: Does ClearAll() remove rows, or just set them to empty strings?  IF it removes rows, then you need to store the ColCount and RowCount into your file so you can restore the original values before loading the cell data.  Which is probably not a bad idea to do anyway.

Comment: When you are saving data, you are storing values from the Rows[] property, but you are using the Cells[] property when reading the values back.  You should be using the Cells[] property when saving values.

Comment: how exactly ? not sure I understand you right ....(tired) ...

Comment: "Does ClearAll() remove rows, or just set them to empty strings?" now this is a million dollar question ... :-) beats me ...

Comment: How can you have consistent outcome with inconsistent coding: 1) if (cxRadiogroup3.ItemIndex and cxRadiogroup2.ItemIndex) = 0 versus 2) //if cxRadiogroup3.ItemIndex = 1 and cxRadiogroup2.ItemIndex = 0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is an old tipp from [SwissDelphiCenter](http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/de/showcode.php?id=941) that could help you

```
// Save StringGrid1 to 'c:\temp.txt':
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SaveStringGrid(StringGrid1, 'c:\temp.txt');
end;

// Load StringGrid1 from 'c:\temp.txt':
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  LoadStringGrid(StringGrid1, 'c:\temp.txt');
end;

// Save a TStringGrid to a file

procedure SaveStringGrid(StringGrid: TStringGrid; const FileName: TFileName);
var
  f:    TextFile;
  i, k: Integer;
begin
  AssignFile(f, FileName);
  Rewrite(f);
  with StringGrid do
  begin
    // Write number of Columns/Rows
    Writeln(f, ColCount);
    Writeln(f, RowCount);
    // loop through cells
    for i := 0 to ColCount - 1 do
      for k := 0 to RowCount - 1 do
        Writeln(F, Cells[i, k]);
  end;
  CloseFile(F);
end;

// Load a TStringGrid from a file

procedure LoadStringGrid(StringGrid: TStringGrid; const FileName: TFileName);
var
  f:          TextFile;
  iTmp, i, k: Integer;
  strTemp:    String;
begin
  AssignFile(f, FileName);
  Reset(f);
  with StringGrid do
  begin
    // Get number of columns
    Readln(f, iTmp);
    ColCount := iTmp;
    // Get number of rows
    Readln(f, iTmp);
    RowCount := iTmp;
    // loop through cells & fill in values
    for i := 0 to ColCount - 1 do
      for k := 0 to RowCount - 1 do
      begin
        Readln(f, strTemp);
        Cells[i, k] := strTemp;
      end;
  end;
  CloseFile(f);
end;
```

I'm trying to understand your code and tried him as good as it is possible for me to rewrite. (it's not tested)

```
procedure TForm1.AdvGlowButton12Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i, j: Integer;
  Seznam: TStrings;
  ApplicationPath: string;
  fileName: string;
  line: string;
begin
  if (cxRadiogroup2.ItemIndex = 0) then begin
    if (cxRadiogroup3.ItemIndex = 0) then
      fileName:= 'A1.txt'
    else
      fileName:= 'A2.txt'

    ApplicationPath:= ExtractFileDir(Application.ExeName);
    Seznam:= TStringList.Create;
    try
      for k:=0 to advStringGrid2.RowCount-1 do begin
        line:= '';
        for i:=0 to advStringGrid2.ColCount-1 do
          line = line + '|' + advStringGrid2.Cells[i, k];
        Seznam.AddStrings(line);
      end;
      Seznam.SaveToFile(ApplicationPath + '\' + fileName);
    finally
      seznam.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.cxRadioGroup2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  splitList: TStringList;
  i, j: Integer;
  Seznam: TStrings;
  ApplicationPath: string;
  fileName: string;
  line: string;
  sepIndex: integer;
begin
  if (cxRadiogroup2.ItemIndex = 0) then begin
    if (cxRadiogroup3.ItemIndex = 0) then
      fileName:= 'A1.txt'
    else
      fileName:= 'A2.txt'

    AdvStringgrid2.ClearAll; // don't know what this does

    ApplicationPath:= ExtractFileDir(Application.ExeName);
    Seznam:= TStringList.Create;
    try
      Seznam.LoadFromFile(fileName);
      advstringGrid2.RowCount:= Seznam.Count;
      splitList:= TStringList.Create;
      for i:=0 to Seznam.Count-1 do begin
        line:= Seznam.Strings [i];
        Split('|', line, splitList);
        advStringGrid2.ColCount:= Max(advStringGrid2.ColCount, splitList.Count);
        for k:=0 to splitList.Count-1 do
          advStringGrid2.Cells[i, k]:= splitList[k];
      end; 
    finally
      splitList.Free;
      seznam.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure Split (const Delimiter: Char; Input: string; const Strings: TStrings);
begin
   Assert(Assigned(Strings));
   Strings.Clear;
   Strings.Delimiter:= Delimiter;
   Strings.DelimitedText:= Input;
end;
```

hope that helps

Comment: To my opinion, refering the wrappers functions from SwissDelphiCenter is only a possible answer to the actual question `How to load and save StringGrid content?` as stated in the excerpt. Still, there seems to be other "hidden" questions, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

How do you know it is overwriting A1.txt?  You are saving the exact same contents in both cases.

Comment: What do you mean by "You are saving the exact same contents in both cases" ??? I think that is happening but dont know what is wrong....

Comment: I clear the contents of the grid before I load new data.Somehow it seems that the data is still there and getting overwritten...Files have different contents...

Comment: The code you showed, commented and all, is saving the exact same Grid with the exact same columns and rows to two separate filenames. So even if the code overwrote A1.txt the second time, how would you know? The new data would be the same as the old data.  I suggest you grab File Monitor from http://www.sysinternals.com and watch what is really happening.

Answer (score 0):

Founded and adapted to my needs. Then shared :-)

```
procedure LoadStringGrid(const AFileName: TFileName; AGrid: TStringGrid);
var
    slRows: TStringList;
    i: integer;
begin
    slRows:= TStringList.Create;
  try
    slRows.LoadFromFile(AFileName);
    for i:= 0 to slRows.Count -1 do
      AGrid.Rows[i +1].CommaText:= slRows[i];
    finally
        slRows.Free;
    end;
end;//  LoadStringGrid
```

```
procedure SaveStringGrid(const AFileName: TFileName; AGrid: TStringGrid);
var
    slRows: TStringList;
    i: integer;
begin
    slRows:= TStringList.Create;
  try
    for i:= 1 to AGrid.RowCount -1 do
        slRows.Add(AGrid.Rows[i].CommaText);
    slRows.SaveToFile(AFileName);
    finally
        slRows.Free;
    end;
end;//  SaveStringGrid
```